# See the attributes of a dataframe but exclude rownames

Tags: r

I'd like to see the attributes of a dataframe but exclude the **$row.names** part.
I'm using attributes().

```
attributes( df )
```

Is there a way to achieve this using this function or do I need to seek a different function?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use

```
atr1 <- attributes(df)
atr1[setdiff(names(atr1), "row.names")]
```

---

If we want in a single step, use `modifyList`

```
 modifyList(attributes(df), list("row.names" = NULL))
```